# Java play 2.0.8 web service " server was unable to process request. root element is missing/invalid"

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

I am invoking a web service using this **code**:

*Promise result = WS.url("https://example/InsightService/service.asmx")
.setQueryParameter("username", "test")
.post("content");*

and i am getting this as response:

> "server was unable to process request. root element is invalid"

and i have tried this **code**:

*Promise result = WS.url("https://example/InsightService/service.asmx")
.setQueryParameter("username", "test")
.post("");*

and for above code i am getting response as:

> server was unable to process request. root element is missing"

Can anyone help me whats wrong with it? or what am i missing.?

thanks

Comment: I think server expects an xml as a body of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more information?? The actual URL and the content you are trying to send? I am telling you this because it seems that the error is in the content of the POST you are sending.

For Example, to check that your code is OK, you can try with google Maps REST API:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal

So the code in play would look like:

```
Promise result = WS.url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json")
.setQueryParameter("origin", "Toronto")
.setQueryParameter("destination", "Montreal").get();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i will try it and let you know.

Comment: great... hope it helps!